# How to fix Bootstrap column grid that doesn't align?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am setting up a form with bootstrap 4 but the columns doesn't align creating unwanted space and reducing the size of the input box.

I tried using different Bootstrap css cdn codes aside the downloaded ones but problem still persists.

```
<!------ Begin Description Section ------->
<div id="Description_details" class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="step body current" id="trade-steps-p-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="false"
    style="display: block;">
    <fieldset class="trade">
      <legend>What are you Buying?</legend>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 required" aria-required="true">
        <label for="ContractName">Give Your Trade a Name
          <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content=" data-original-title="" title="">
              <i class=" fa fa-question-circle"></i>
          </a>
        </label>
        <input name="data[Contract][name]" class="form-control" maxlength="50" type="text" id="ContractName"
          required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6 required" aria-required="true">
        <label for="">Industry Classification</label>
        <select name="data[Contract][industry]" class="form-control" id="" required="required" aria-required="true"
          aria-invalid="false">
          <option value="GENERAL_GOODS_SERVICES" selected="selected">General Goods &amp; Services</option>
          <option value="AGRICULTURE_LIVESTOCK_GAME">Agriculture, Livestock &amp; Game</option>
          <option value="ART_ANTIQUES_COLLECTIBLES">Art, Antiques &amp; Collectibles</option>
          <option value="BUSINESS_SALE_BROKING">Business Sale &amp; Broking</option>
          <option value="VEHICLES_WATERCRAFT">Cars, Bikes &amp; Watercraft</option>
          <option value="CONSTRUCTION">Construction</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To have the input areas align as col-md-6 on the left and right respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what are you want, briefly explain in your question

Comment: Bootstrap has default values for Margin and Padding too . . . .   Dig deeper.

Comment: You shouldn't mix your content with the layout grid so badly. Place your column element immediately inside your row element, and your content inside that. You'll eliminate many headaches by keeping things separate.

Answer (score 0):

Set Custom Margin for that class

```
. col-md-6 {
 margin: 5px !important;
}
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using col-md-6 thats why input field is not fitting to the row.You should use col-lg-12 or col-md-12. check documentation how grid system works here [Bootstrap 4 grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where i used `w-100` to use the full width.
My ***Tipp*** is to **always start with a small screen** where i used `col-12`.
When the screen get's bigger they can be side by side with `col-md-6` for both.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!------ Begin Description Section ------->
<div id="Description_details" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="step body current w-100" id="trade-steps-p-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
      <fieldset class="trade">
        <legend>What are you Buying?</legend>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="ContractName">Give Your Trade a Name
          <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content=" data-original-title="" title="">
              <i class=" fa fa-question-circle"></i>
          </a>
        </label>
            <input name="data[Contract][name]" class="form-control" maxlength="50" type="text" id="ContractName" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="">Industry Classification</label>
            <select name="data[Contract][industry]" class="form-control" id="" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
              <option value="GENERAL_GOODS_SERVICES" selected="selected">General Goods &amp; Services</option>
              <option value="AGRICULTURE_LIVESTOCK_GAME">Agriculture, Livestock &amp; Game</option>
              <option value="ART_ANTIQUES_COLLECTIBLES">Art, Antiques &amp; Collectibles</option>
              <option value="BUSINESS_SALE_BROKING">Business Sale &amp; Broking</option>
              <option value="VEHICLES_WATERCRAFT">Cars, Bikes &amp; Watercraft</option>
              <option value="CONSTRUCTION">Construction</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```